# ASP.NET Core MVC: ModelState value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC project. Currently, I'm trying to add actors from `Create.cshtml` view. The view has three fields and all of them are required:

- ProfilePictureURL
- FullName
- Bio

I'm making these fields required with some data annotation attributes in the model.

In the controller, I am using `[Bind]` data annotation in the parentheses of the respective action method. Inside of its body I'm checking `!ModelState.IsValid` which is expected to be false. On the contrary, it's true and I don't get it why.

Here are some screenshots of model, controller and view.

Controller:

[image]

Model:

[image]

View:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why my `!IsModelState.IsValid` is always true?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, screenshot is not accepted to let other contributor expects to resolve your issue. Please share exact code snippet in order to investigate your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Inside of its body I'm checking !ModelState.IsValid which is expected
> to be false. On the contrary, it's true and I don't get it why.

Altough, you haven't shared your code snippet in correct way and your `asp.net core` version information as well. However, if you use older version than `asp.net core 6` in that case you might encounter this issue. Because, in older version of `asp.net core` when you use `DataAnnotations` in that scenario the property without any annotation doesn't take into account. In your case
`public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }` has no `DataAnnotations` which would comletely be ignored in older than `asp.net core 6`.

**Debug in asp.net core 6:**

[image]

Note: As you can see in `asp.net core 6` as you haven't use any `DataAnnotations` on `Movies` property therefore, by default it will consider as `[Required]` and finally `!ModelState.IsValid` will be always `false`. [You can check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#non-nullable-reference-types-and-required-attribute)

**Debug in asp.net core Older: 3.XXX:**

[image]

**Note:** Here `!ModelState.IsValid` always true because in older version it will consider as `nun-nullable` and always consider true. [You can check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#required-validation-on-the-server-1)

**Solution:**

You should redefine your `public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }` and tell what kind of behavior should be expected here. But in `dot net core 6` or higher version, it will autometically consider as false not matter you use `dataAnnotation`

Comment: big thanks. I'll keep in mind about the snippets 

Comment: Glad to assist you on this.

Comment: Yesterday, when I was writing this question, I was having mental break down due to this error. I was like John Malkovich from the Space Force movie - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zpCOYkdvTQ


Comment: I got your point.